# Что входит в состав .NET?

Tags: .net, clr

Можно ли сказать,что в состав .NET входят CLR и классы(FCL).Или там есть что-то ещё?

Answer (score 3):

Нет, в состав .NET на самом деле входит больше, чем только CLR и FCL.

**.NET как технология** включает:

- Спецификацию Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) ECMA-334 (и аналогичную ISO), которая описывает принципы работы CLR, систему управляемых типов, набор инструкций байткода, формат файлов сборок, структуру стандартных библиотек и др.
- Спецификации языков C# (ECMA-335) и C++/CLI (ECMA-372)
- Реализации этих спецификаций в виде платформ (.NET Framework, .NET Core) и компиляторов.
- Прочее ПО, не имеющее прямого отношения к CLI, но все равно являющееся естественной частью разработки под .NET, например .NET Framework SDK для Visual Studio.

**.NET Framework как программный продукт** включает:

- Исполняющую среду CLR
- Библиотеку классов
- Компиляторы C# и VB.NET
- Систему сборки MSBuild
- Набор специфических утилит командной строки, вроде aspnet_regiis.exe
- Прочие служебные компоненты, например [Счетчики производительности](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/performance-counters)

Правда, MSBuild и компиляторы языков в состав .NET Framework включены устаревшие, на уровне C# 5.0, и в .NET Core от их включения уже отказались - вместо этого компиляторы Roslyn поставляются с Visual Studio и в составе отдельных NuGet-пакетов. Но все равно, и архитектурно и структурно .NET - больше, чем только CLR и FCL.